# fabricjs disable auto move operating object to top

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

- In new version(>1.7) fabricjs,when I operate active Object.It will auto move their own z-index to top,but i don't want it.
- So, I just can use old version(1.5) and use `moveTo` to finish my requirement,but I want use some new feature in new version.
- I can't find any message about z-index in new version,what can I do to  keep old operate active Object way.

  1. in fabricjs 1.5 [code](https://jsfiddle.net/5r4m4Lkh/)
  2. in fabricjs 1.7 [code](https://jsfiddle.net/5r4m4Lkh/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a preserveObjectStacking property, that should be default to false, that should do exactly what you need.
I guess that maybe 1.5 had a bug and was not working correctly?

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html

Search for preserveObjectStacking in that page.

```js
var _canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { preserveObjectStacking: true });

var text1 = new fabric.Text('word one...')

var text2 = new fabric.Text('word two...', {
  top: 30,
  left: 40,
  backgroundColor: '#f00'
})


_canvas.add(text1)

_canvas.add(text2)
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.17/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you so much.This is the perfect solution to my problem！